# How to grab data from the 2nd most recent record for each student?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Working in a school district I have a database that contains information about students' Education Plans. I'm using Management Studio to access a SQL Server 2012 database. I need to grab the information from their 2nd most recent plan.  Here are the columns.

- Database Name is `PlansAnoka`
- Table name is `dbo.plans`

Columns:

- `PlanID` (primary key)
- `StudentID` (these would all be unique for each student)
- `PlanDate` (this is the column that I want to use as the date to pull the 2nd most recent record.
- `Meeting Date` (this is just another data point that I need)

I know how to create a query to grab the most recent one, but not the 2nd most recent one. AND I need 2nd most recent record for EACH student. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *from their 2nd most recent plan*, who's 2nd most recent plan?, one row for every student?

Comment: Yes, one row for every student.  Thanks!  I edited my original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` function and partition by `StudentID`:

```
WITH A AS
(
  SELECT 
    StudentID , 
    PlanDate ,
    MeetingDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY PlanDate DESC) rownum
  FROM dbo.plans
) 
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE rownum=2
```

Comment: I've got some learnin' to do.  I'm not exactly sure how this works (new to SQL), but it definitely does.  And it seems like a very eloquent solution.  Looks like I need to do some more research on partition.  Seems like a very useful tool.  THANKS!

Comment: Yes - aggregate partitioning is very useful, but be careful not to overuse it.  Start with basic grouping/aggregation and use partitions when that doesn't get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number` if you want get `n'th` record:

```
select * from 
(select studentid , 
 plandata ,
 row_number() over(partition by plandata order by plandata desc) rn
from dbo.plans) t
where t.rn=2 -- or n
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post to make it more clear.  I need to grab the 2nd most recent record for every student.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
select * from
    (select *, row_number() over (partition by StudentID order by PlanDate desc) Rank
     from dbo.plans) p
where p.Rank = 2
```

Reference link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: This worked well, thanks!  ( I know it said that I shouldn't just say thanks, but seems rude not to - let me know if as a contributor if you'd prefer I not say thanks and I'll learn the culture of this forum ) I'm going to have to learn some more about partition now.  Seems like a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

```
select * from
(
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() 
  over(partition by StudentID order by plandate desc) 
  as Row from dbo.plans
) temp
WHERE temp.Row = 2
```

Comment: This worked well, thanks!  ( I know it said that I shouldn't just say thanks, but seems rude not to - let me know if as a contributor if you'd prefer I not say thanks and I'll learn the culture of this forum ) I'm going to have to learn some more about partition now.  Seems like a useful tool.

Comment: Maybe you can vote up the answer if it is correct? I devoted some time on this....

Comment: It says I'm not allowed to vote because my reputation is below 15.  I did put a green check mark on the first answer I tried that worked.  That was by D Stanley.  I wanted to try the others as well because it helps me learn.